# Why do I need to make my electron window bigger than my canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, electron

JS

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 450, height: 600,
    'title' : 'Quantum Pilot', 'transparent' : true,
    'web-preferences' : {'allow-displaying-insecure-content' : true}});
```

HTML

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="black">
<center>
    <div id="game_container">
    </div>
</center>
</body>
```

Front JS

```
generateCanvas() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    Thing.prototype.scale = 1;
    canvas.width = 450 * Thing.prototype.scale;
    canvas.height = 600;
```

When I run my application, scrollbars are present unless I use `style="overflow: hidden"` in the html `body`.

I can get rid of the scrollbars by adding 50px to the Electron window. But I'm confused as to why this is happening.

How can I just make a window and the canvas be the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions you specify in `BrowserWindow` options are not the dimensions of the body but the dimensions of the window, including the frame.

If you want the inside of your window to match what you specify as options, you should use `useContentSize: true`

From https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#class-browserwindow

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `height` properties/attributes represents the coordinate space of the canvas, and not the dimensions of the element.

Use `<canvas style="width: 450px; height: 600px;"></canvas>` instead to specify the dimensions of your canvas.

Or more simply, if you want it fullscreen: `<canvas style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></canvas>`

Check if `<body>` or `<html>` has no padding or margin too.

See [canvas attributes documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Attributes)

Comment: There's no padding, but that style on the canvas did not fix the issue.. trying the vh

Comment: Maybe you could update your files in your questions, I see no CSS or canvas element for example ;) it'll help a bit to resolve your case